# MySQL won't group by link

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, phpmyadmin

I have a SQL table which contains datas such as an ID, a link (hyperlink), a category and a timestamp.

The result should be a SQL query which return how often one specified link exists for a day. That basically means I have to execute a SQL query which counts the ID and groups by the link.

But for no reason exactly this is not working...
This is how my SQL Table is looking:

[image]

But when I execute this simple SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, DAY(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Datum, link as URL 
FROM 4184_lead_tracking 
WHERE datum >= '2017-12-01' AND datum <= '2017-12-31' 
GROUP BY link 
ORDER BY DAY(datum) ASC`
```

I get this result:
[image]

You see. He is merging those both links into one:

1. https://radlvoo.de/blog/produkt/haibike-seet-hardfour-life-1-0-2016-rh-groesse-30/
2. https://radlvoo.de/blog/produkt/haibike-seet-hardfour-life-1-0-2017-rh-groesse-30/

But they are diffrent. One is for 2016 and one for 2017... Why is he doing this and how can I group them correct?

I would appreciate any kind of help!
Kind regards

Comment: It's not grouping those together, the 2017 link is being excluded. You can tell because the count in your query is 1, not 2.. Are you showing us the full query? As written, it should not produce that result

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE 4184_lead_tracking`, as the excact table and key definitions might be relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway you should also group by day (because is non involved in aggreagtion function), or don't use that field in the SELECT, because it can only contain one value of the (many) different rows in your GROUP:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, DAY(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Datum, link as URL 
FROM 4184_lead_tracking 
WHERE datum >= '2017-12-01' AND datum <= '2017-12-31' GROUP BY link, Datum
ORDER BY DAY(datum) ASC
```

Otherwise you could obatin unpredictable result for column  not involved  in group by and not in aggreagation function. Read more about the handling of [`GROUP BY` in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and the [SQL Mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: You can use the `Datum` alias in `GROUP BY` instead of repeating the expression.

Comment: Yes  .. the missing datum in group return unpredcitable values for this column ..that made you believe that the values for the link column were not correct .. This is due to the improper use of group by managed by previous versions of mysql .. in versions starting from 5.7 the use of column without aggregation functions not mentioned in group is no longer allowed just to avoid these anomalies